# Available Filters With Specified Ranges In SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssrs-2008

I am working on a Chart in my report.

As I have too many records where `CountId` = 1, I have set up a filter showing an available values list like this:

CountId :

- 1
- 2
- 3
- Between 4 to 6
- Between 7 to 9
- Above 10

If I set the available value 1 or 2 or 3 it shows results, but I don`t know how to set a filter for between and above.

I want a filter some thing like this - available filters are:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- Above 5 or greater than equal to 5

Comment: This question is not very clear at all...

Comment: I have a chart which shows affected users. there are hundreds of users affected only one time. So i want there a filter which based on Incident Count.  I set available values as @Count = 1, @count = 2, @Count = 3, @Count = 4.
But now i want to set another value that is @count =< 5. I don`t know how to set greater than values so kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a mix of operators, so maybe you should look at an expression based filter to try and handle these different cases, something like:

**Expression (type `Text`):**

```
=Switch(Parameters!Count.Value = "1" and Fields!Count.Value = 1, "Include"
  , Parameters!Count.Value = "2" and Fields!Count.Value = 2, "Include"
  , Parameters!Count.Value = "3" and Fields!Count.Value = 3, "Include"
  , Parameters!Count.Value = "4 to 6" and Fields!Count.Value >= 4 and Fields!Count.Value <= 6, "Include"
  , Parameters!Count.Value = "7 to 9" and Fields!Count.Value >= 7 and Fields!Count.Value <= 9, "Include"
  , Parameters!Count.Value = "Above 10" and Fields!Count.Value >= 10, "Include"
  , true, "Exclude")
```

**Operator:**

```
=
```

**Value:**

```
Include
```

This assumes a string parameter `Count` populated with the above values.

This works by calculating the parameter and field combinations to produce a constant, either `Include` or `Exclude`, then displaying all rows that return `Include`.

As mentioned in a comment, it's difficult to follow exactly what you're asking here. I've done my best but if you have more questions it would be best to update the question with some sample data and how you'd like this data displayed.